# Angular + Karma/Jasmine: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'md.data.table' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using Karma and Jasmine to test my Angular application.

I have this spec below:

```
"use strict";

describe("SuperHeroService", function () {
    var SuperHeroService, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('beAwesome'));
    beforeEach(module("beASuperHero"));    
    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (_SuperHeroService_, _$httpBackend_) {
            SuperHeroService = _SuperHeroService_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;                      
        });
    });

    it("should initialize correctly", function () {
        expect(SuperHeroService).toBeDefined();
    });
```

The `md.data.table` dependency is included in the beAwesome module, which I'm including in my beforeEach block. beAwesome module is called in beASuperHero as well.

I've also referenced the SuperHeroService, beAwesome and beASuperHero in my karma.conf file.

However, I cannot figure out why the md-data-table (Github project: https://github.com/iamisti/md-data-table) won't be instantiated and keeps breaking, no matter what I do:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module beASuperHero due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module md.data.table due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'md.data.table' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I'm sure I'm just missing some configuration or a line of code but after hours of searching, I haven't found anything that's been helpful! Any hints to get unstuck is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the file where the `md.data.table` module is defined in your Karma config's `files` array?

Comment: Yes, I've added ```'bower_components/md-data-table/dist/md-data-table.js'``` and ```'bower_components/md-data-table/dist/md-data-table-templates.js'``` as per what I can see according to the bower package. I thought that'd solve the issue but it hasn't unfortunately.

Comment: And those paths are correct? Your `bower_components` directory is in the same directory as `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: Also, it appears the correct module name is `mdDataTable`, not `md.data.table`

Comment: ... ie, your `beASuperHero` module should have `angular.module('beASuperHero', ['mdDataTable'])`

Comment: Actually, the name of the module is ```md.data.table``` and if changed to ```mdDataTable``` fails to load the grid. I wouldn't name it this way if it was my module, but I'm using one found online.

Comment: It's totally not ~ https://github.com/iamisti/md-data-table/blob/master/app/modules/app.js#L4

Comment: Assuming that your app actually works when you have `'md.data.table'` as a dependency in your `'beASuperHero'` module, you should revisit my first comment ~ include the file that defines the `'md.data.table'` module in your `files` array. FYI, it is **not** `bower_components/md-data-table/dist/md-data-table.js`

Comment: You sure you're not using this one ~ https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table ? If you are, the path is `bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.js`

Comment: Hey Phil, you're totally right mate! I completely installed and referenced the wrong package. Silly me. If you move your comments into an answer, I'll accept it as the accepted answer bud!